How are brake cables installs for drop and flat lever combo brake system?
I have an old traitor wander which is a discontinued series. The brake system is curious but interesting. I'd like to reroute brake cables and levers but I don't want to open a can of worms. Is there a special brake cable needed for this kind of combination brake lever system?


Nothing special required. The additional brake lever simply moves the housing to actuate the brake while the actual road bike brake lever only pulls the cable. Both actions have the same effect: Moving the brake.
In a sense the additional brake lever works like a very quick barrel adjuster (and with a lever instead of threads).
There is a ParkTool Tutorial for installing them: https://www.parktool.com/en-us/blog/repair-help/in-line-brake-levers

Also, the inner cable passes from the drop-brake lever through the interrupter lever and down to the caliper like normal.  The second lever "interrupts" the outer only.   OP also has a shifter installed in the tip of the drop which slightly confuses the photo.

@Criggie you're correct. The lowest visible housing is the barend shifter.
